# how to use List in my project by shared_preferences

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been using `shared_preferences` in String type that it is ok. but my program has an error when call `getList()`.
"the method getStringList was called on null".
how to use it correctly. thanks for helping.

```
List<String> list = ['sony.com','apple.com'];

Future<bool> saveList() async {
  return await prefs.setStringList("key", list);
}

List<String> getList() {
  return prefs.getStringList("key") ?? list;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the complete class? The error is not caused by the code you show... `prefs` is null but you don't show where you set it

Comment: where do you instantiate the sharedpreferences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works fine, make sure you call the shared preferences correctly

```flutter
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<String> list = ['sony.com','apple.com'];
    localStorage.setStringList("key", list);

    List stringList = localStorage.getStringList("key") ?? list;

    print(stringList);
```